# How would I ask for superking(extra large) cigarettes in german?

Tags: translation

In Scotland, I always buy superking cigarettes, and I was wondering if there was a word for this I could use when I travel to Berlin.

Comment: **On-topic**, because clearly not a dictionary term. JPS (John Player Special) markets *king* and *super king* sized cigarettes, apart from their normal cig lengths. This seems to have become a generic term for overlong cigarettes. I went through relevant meta discussions and the help center and couldn’t find a reason to close this.

Comment: @Philipp As written, I still read that body text as about [*one brand*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkings).

Comment: @LangLangC To me, the question doesn't sound like »I always smoke Superking, how can I buy that brand/product in Germany?« (that question would be quite silly, and off topic), but it sounds like »extra long cigarettes are called superking (after a brand name), how do I ask for that in Germany«.

Comment: @Philipp Possible. Q then needs to be edited to differentiate between Superkings (which are extra long and tasty) and super-king-sized (any cigarette that is 99mm long and called a 100)

Answer (score 2):

This is what a German tobacco producer says:

> Die meisten Fertig-Zigaretten werden heutzutage im Format „King Size" verkauft. Dieses entspricht einer Länge von 83 mm. Ebenso gibt es **Super-King-Size Zigaretten** mit einer Länge von 99 mm. <sup>[Reemtsma](http://www.reemtsma.com/das-unternehmen/produkte/alles-wissenswerte-ueber-zigaretten-co/)</sup>

So it should be safe to ask for super-king cigarettes as you are used to. Not all brands come in super-king size however.

Answer (score 2):

Germans buying such long cigarettes almost always say "100er" ("hunderter"), sometimes "die langen" / "lange" combined with the brand name.

King-Size and Super-King-Size maybe the official names, but it seems that no "end user" uses these words.

The German wikipedia article only references "King size" once, in Germany brands are marketed as "100s" (see for instance https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_(Zigarettenmarke), not as Super King Size.